# User Datagram Protocol (UDP) protocol can error control?

Tags: udp, errors

1. UDP can congestion control?
2. UDP can flow control?
3. UDP have some error correction mechanism?

Comment: UDP is a fire-and-forget, best-effort protocol that sends a datagram without caring that it actually reaches the destination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UDP itself has no mechanisms for neither flow control, nor congestion control, and no error *correction*. If the application's datastream needs any of these, then they must be implemented within the application.

However, UDP may have error *detection*: The UDP header has a 16bit checksum field, but it's use (with UDP-on-IPv4) is not mandatory (however it is mandatory with UDP on IPv6) and it may be all-zeros.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043680/how-to-enable-udp-checksums, but now we're digressing into upper layers and host related topics, and that is close to becoming off-topic here.

Comment: if detect some error in checksum,can drop udp segemnt?

Comment: UDP checksum generation validation done by the end system, by setting socket options aproppriately.  It is up to the application what it wants to do with an UDP datagram with incorrect checksum. But this is becoming off-topic now.